# Linux flash drives

Tags: usb-flash-drive

How can I determine the address of a pen drive in Linux?

My task is to create a file on my pen drive dynamically - as soon as I insert the pen drive, the file should be created.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using udev.

**Edit**: Here's a similar question which was posted in 2007. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-detect-programatically-if-a-usb-device-is-is-plugged-in-plugged-out-524568/

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu at least (meaning that the drive automounts), a drive's files can be found under `/media/<drivelabel>`. The drive label is either something random if you didn't set one or what you set it to.

Comment: Thanks for that ...But can i get the drive label dynamically ?? or if i want to set it permanently,how to do that ??

Comment: @R-The_Master https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RenameUSBDrive

Answer (score 0):

+1 for the UDEV
Create an UDEV rule that runs a script, whenever a device with a specific UUID is inserted.

To determine the mountpoint of a device with e.g. uuid of *"95738a33-589f-498d-8595-a81207f45dde"*, you can use the following ugly-but-working one-liner:

```
grep $(ls -lah /dev/disk/by-uuid/95738a33-589f-498d-8595-a81207f45dde | grep -o "sd[a-z]*[0-9]*") /etc/mtab |  awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: I like that Idea....but the issue is that I just wanted the starting address of the drive in a variable like long x ...This is a variable in a C function....so how do i do that ??